# MAUI Handler Xaml to Platform Connection

Tags: c#, android, ios, handler, maui

I am using the handler feature of MAUI, but the methods in the platform specific classes are not being called.

This is the click event for the xaml page:

```
private void ActivateCamera(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cameraView.MakePhoto();
}
```

This are the Interface and the View classes:

```
public interface ICameraView : IView
{
    void MakePhoto();
}

public class CameraView : View, ICameraView
{
    CameraViewHandler StrongHandler => Handler as CameraViewHandler;

    public void MakePhoto() => StrongHandler?.Invoke(nameof(MakePhoto), null);
}
```

This is the Handler:

```
public class CameraViewHandler : ViewHandler<ICameraView, NativePlatformCameraPreviewView>
{

    public static CommandMapper<ICameraView, CameraViewHandler> CameraCommandMapper = new()
    {
        [nameof(ICameraView.MakePhoto)] = MapMakePhoto
    };

    public static void MapMakePhoto(CameraViewHandler handler, ICameraView cameraView, object? parameter) 
        => handler.TakePhoto();

    public void TakePhoto() => _cameraController?.TakePicture();
     // The TakePicture method is implemented in the iOS and android files, but as said, is not being executed
}
```

I have this in MauiProgramm:

```
handlers.AddHandler(typeof(CameraView), typeof(CameraViewHandler));
```

Can someone see why this is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check the official document about [creating a custom control using handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/create?view=net-maui-7.0)? The mapped method should in the platform custom handler class.

So CameraViewHandler.cs should be such as:

```
public partial class CameraViewHandler : ViewHandler<ICameraView, NativePlatformCameraPreviewView>
{

    public static CommandMapper<ICameraView, CameraViewHandler> CameraCommandMapper = new()
    {
        [nameof(ICameraView.MakePhoto)] = MapMakePhoto
    };
}
```

And the MapMakePhoto method in the CameraViewHandler.Android.cs:

```
 public static void MapMakePhoto(CameraViewHandler handler, ICameraView cameraView)
{
    handler.PlatformView?.NativeMethod();
}
```

For more information, you can refer to [the official sample on the github about the handlers](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/tree/main/6.0/UserInterface/Handlers/CreateHandlerDemo/VideoDemos/Handlers).

**Update**

Don't forget the construction method of the handler:

```
public CameraViewHandler() : base(CameraViewMapper, CameraCommandMapper) { }
```

Comment: To have specific files for each Platform is more like a structure design thing, nevertheless, you pointed me to the right direction, thanks! This is what i was missing:  
                                                                                                                                        
 public CameraViewHandler() : base(CameraViewMapper, CameraCommandMapper)
    {
        
    }